# Align multiple columns in excel based on matching values in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

Move values in column B and C so that matching values in column A and B are in the same row.  Values in column B and C should move together by inserting blank cells when there is no match between columns A and B.

Before:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x |
| 2 | 3 | y |
| 3 |  |  |

After:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | y |

I have used the following function to place matching values between two columns adjacent to column A, which worked:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C:C,0)),"",INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,C:C,0)))
```

However, this does not solve my problem of also moving non-matching values in a third column (column C).

I suspect I need a VBA macro for this but have not had success, including with help from chat GPT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=HSTACK(A1:A3,IFNA(INDEX(B1:C2,XMATCH(A1:A3,B1:B2),{1,2}),""))
```